# Set a column Text value based on a condition in WPF grid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a integer value(0,1,2) for which I need to display text as 'Error,Forward,Reverse' respectively.

Can I achieve this in form.xaml using setter property of GridViewDataColumn .If so how and if not what will be the other value. 
Here for data column we have to define binding as `DataMemberBinding="{Binding Direction}"` where 'Direction' is UInt16 and this Direction property is part of an Observable collection.Thus for every change I need to display data as string accordingly.

I simply have column defined in my grid as

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Direction}" UniqueName= "Direction" Header="Direction" Width="85" TextAlignment="Left"  HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DisplayIndex="9" IsFilteringDeferred="True" >
```

How can I add trigger to achieve that?

Comment: You can achieve this in multiple ways. Either Converters, Triggers or an additional Property in your ViewModel. Its hard to suggest you the best solution since you posted no code

Comment: @lokusking edited my question as per your comment. I haven't coded any thing regarding this as such . How can i use the Trigger to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user DataTrigger/IValueConvertor to achieve

**DataTrigger :**

```
 <Style.Triggers>
      <!-- 1st trigger -->
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Value="0">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Error"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <!-- 2nd trigger -->
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Forward"/>
      </DataTrigger>
      <!-- 3rd trigger -->

  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Reverse"/>
  </DataTrigger>

</Style.Triggers>
```

**Convertor:**

```
 <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Direction,Convertor={StaticResource InttoDateConverter }" UniqueName= "Direction" Header="Direction" Width="85" TextAlignment="Left"  HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DisplayIndex="9" IsFilteringDeferred="True" >


public class InttoDateConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            switch (value.ToString().ToLower())
            {
                case "0":
                    return "Error!";
                case "1":
                    return "Forward";

                default:
                    return "Reverse";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           // only for two way binding
        }
    }
```

**DataGrid Column Binding :**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Direction" >
      <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Direction, Converter={StaticResource IntoToDataConvertor}, Mode=Default}"  />
             </DataTemplate>
      </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Tried Converter using following code

`xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MyForm;assembly=">`
`<Grid.Resources>
<custom:InttoDateConverter x:Key="convertDirection"></custom:InttoDateConverter>
</Grid.Resources>

<telerik1:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Direction,Converter={StaticResource convertDirection }}" UniqueName= "Direction" Header="Direction" Width="85" TextAlignment="Left"  HeaderTextAlignment="Center" DisplayIndex="9" IsFilteringDeferred="True" />`

Method is getting called but Text not getting changed as expected. What I am missing?

Comment: you can last solution DataGridColumn directly will not support Converters .  Define celltemplate then try it

Comment: Using Style option was also giving some error as style is not a property of GridviewDataColumn.. Does that also required any other changes to work?